# Is there a reason why bb.person gets filled but a.Person does not?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Person struct {
    First string `json:"name"`
}

type person struct {
    Last string `json:"name"`
}

type A struct {
    *Person `json:"person"`
}

func (a *A) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    type alias A

    bb := struct {
        *person `json:"person"`
        *alias      
    }{
        alias: (*alias)(a),
    }

    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &bb); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", bb.person)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    b := []byte(`{"person": {"name": "bob"}}`)
    a := &A{}

    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, a); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", a.Person)
}
```

results in:

```
&{Last:bob}
<nil>
```

Why does bb.person and a.Person have the same struct tag but only bb.person gets filled in? I haven't been able to find the appropriate documentation but why does this happen and is it guaranteed to always happen?

https://play.golang.org/p/Fvo_hg3U6r

Comment: Because `json.Unmarshal` unmarshals a json value only once, and given the structure of `bb`, `person` takes precendence according to the rules which `Unmarshal` follows, whatever they may be.

Comment: I guess that's my question...what is the "rule" that applies here?

Comment: `bb.person.Last` vs `bb.alias.Person.First`, one's closer to the root than the other? Just guessing.

Comment: Try to simplify construction with type aliases. Looks like finally on has 2 fields with the same tag `json:"person"`. And unmarshallee fills first.